# json data isn't showing in Layout but It shows when I come here from another layout

Tags: android, json, fragment

**json data isn't showing in Layout but It shows when an activity is done**

I have following code for Jsonobject. I am using **Tabs in my application.** Initially it is not showing but when **I move from another tab** to my json tab  it shows the data of the json object.

Please help me to find the mistake.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    JsonObjectRequest myReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.18.235:7777/cric/news.php",
              null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try {
                       JSONArray posts = response.getJSONArray("data");
                       for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject temp = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                           String author = temp.getString("author");
                           String content = temp.getString("content");
                           String date = temp.getString("date");
                           String imageUrl = temp.getString("imageUrl");
                           String time = temp.getString("time");
                           String title = temp.getString("title");
                           String url = temp.getString("url");
                           Log.i("jsontag",title);
                           newsFeed.add(new NewsItem(title, content,R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery,author,"2-2-2018","1-05pm","https://www.inshorts.com/en/news/tardigrades-selected-among-1st-species-to-leave-solar-system-1509779328721","http://www.deepspace.ucsb.edu/projects/ets?utm_source=inshorts&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=fullarticle "));
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception e){
                       Log.i("myTag",e.toString());
                   }
                }
            },new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("errorTaf",error.toString());

        }
    }
    );
    queue.add(myReq);
```

Comment: Where are you showing the objects those are being stored in `newsFeed`?

Comment: I have shown this is by ConvertView . I have override the getView method  and set it by title , author.

Comment: That means you are using a `ListView` to show your data. Right? Then where's the adapter of your `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

Please invoke `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or `TabActivity.onContentChanged()` to update view.

Comment: By adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  it is not working and I am not able understood TabActivity.onContentChanged() method. Could you please explain in breif.